# regular expression to tease out the strings that contain at least two 0s and at most one 1?

Tags: regex, unix

I have tried `(^.*(?0){2}.*$)` to catch the 0's but don't know how to catch the 1's

So for the following data:

```
00
110
100
11110011
00111101
00101010
11000000
00000001
10000000
```

The ones that would return would be 100, 00000001, and 10000000

Comment: Should it match 001, and 010? How about 00001? (You said _at least_, not _at most_).

Comment: Are other characters allowed besides `0` and `1`?

Comment: Shouldn't `00` match? It has at least two 0s, and no 1s, which satisfies 'at most one 1'.

Answer (score 2):

If your characters are just `0`s and `1`s like in your example you can do:

```
^(0+10+|100+|0+01)$
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ0jD0/3).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*0.*0.*)(?=.*1.*)(?!.*1.*1.*).*$
```

which is the same as:

```
^(?=.*0.*0.*)(?=[^1]*1[^1]*$).*$
```

---

Use look-ahead assertion:

- at least 2 `zero`
- at least 1 `one`
- at most 1 `one`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wW5lT5/5)

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
^(?=(?:.*0){2})(?=[^1]*1[^1]*$)([01]*)$
```

- `^`  anchor at beginning
- `(?=(?:.*0){2})`  lookahead for at least two 0's
- `(?=[^1]*1[^1]*$)`  lookahead for only one '1' to the end
- `([01]*)`  capture any amount of 0's and 1's or change to `(\d*)` if required
- `$` anchor at end
  [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cB3fQ1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative lookahead to filter out lines with two 1's or zero or one 0:

```
^(?!.*1.*1|[^0]*(0[^0]*)?$)
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for any combination of numbers.

```
^(?=[02-9]*1[02-9]*$)\d*0\d*0\d*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/8)